# RSS Feeds WordPress (.COM)

Tags: wordpress, rss

Is there a way (hack or work-around) to display RSS feeds on a page in a WordPress (.com) blog? I do not want to use the RSS widget because I do not want the feed to be displayed on every page. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress.com doesn't allow javascript, which is probably the only other way for this to work. Maybe you should move to WP.org?

Answer (score 1):

Can you run javascript on a page at .com?

[Developer's Guide - Google AJAX Feed API - Google Code](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/)

If not, might be time to self-host Wordpress. There are cheap hosts out there.